# em1: Watchdog timeout -- resetting - freebsd 8.3 / network down

Tags: networking, timeout, freebsd, watchdog

i have a major issue that i can't find nor heads nor tails of. I have googled this error, but i have not found any relevant solutions.

The problem:

I have about 8 servers, all running freebsd 8.3 p3 / p4. This fileserver is pushing around 300-400 mb/s.

This is the second time it happens. The network card just seems to die. I have 2 network cards in it, and i can reach the server via private network, and it all works okay, only that the public network is completely down. I have tried restarting the network interfaces: /etc/rc.d/netif restart && service routing restart | ifconfig em1 down && ifconfig em1 up, but with no success.

I can only bring the connectivity back if i reboot the server.

Below is the output from dmesg.boot that shows the network card drivers info.

```
em0: <Intel(R) PRO/1000 Network Connection 7.3.2> port 0xf020-0xf03f mem 0xf7b00000-0xf7b1ffff,0xf7b25000-0xf7b25fff irq 20 at device 25.0 on pci0
em0: Using an MSI interrupt
em0: [FILTER]
em0: Ethernet address: 00:25:90:7a:8e:9f
ehci0: <EHCI (generic) USB 2.0 controller> mem 0xf7b24000-0xf7b243ff irq 16 at device 26.0 on pci0
em1: <Intel(R) PRO/1000 Network Connection 7.3.2> port 0xd000-0xd01f mem 0xf7900000-0xf791ffff,0xf7920000-0xf7923fff irq 16 at device 0.0 on pci3
em1: Using MSIX interrupts with 3 vectors
em1: [ITHREAD]
em1: [ITHREAD]
em1: [ITHREAD]
em1: Ethernet address: 00:25:90:7a:8e:9e

----------------------------

pciconf -lv
em1@pci0:3:0:0: class=0x020000 card=0x000015d9 chip=0x10d38086 rev=0x00 hdr=0x00
    vendor     = 'Intel Corporation'
    device     = 'Intel 82574L Gigabit Ethernet Controller (82574L)'
    class      = network
    subclass   = ethernet
em0@pci0:0:25:0:        class=0x020000 card=0x150215d9 chip=0x15028086 rev=0x05 hdr=0x00
    vendor     = 'Intel Corporation'
    class      = network
    subclass   = ethernet
```

---

I would really love some help to debug and fix this, because it usually happens while i am sleeping, at random days, and it's driving me crazy. I love my sleep.

Comment: i think this question should be migrated to serverfault.  Did you try 9.0?

Answer (score 2):

This is a supermicro server, right?

cat /var/run/dmesg.boot | grep MSI
em0: Using an MSI interrupt
em1: Using MSIX interrupts with 3 vectors

Your answer is probably here: http://forums.freebsd.org/showthread.php?t=27736